# Using unset() while iterating over array to remove empty values

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Trying to remove empty values from array like this. It does miss one key each time i use unset(). I know there might be better way to complete task, but i need to know why current code is one missing some keys?

```
$values_arr = array(
   0 => "Text",
   1 => "",
   2 => "",
   3 => "Text",
   4 => "",
   5 => "Text"
);
```

**Works in theory**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values_arr); $i++) {
    if ( empty($values_arr[$i]) ) {
        echo "<br> Blank key found " . $i . ", value was >" . $values_arr[$i] . "<";
        //Unset commented out
        //unset($values_arr[$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($values_arr);
```

**Output**

```
Blank key found 1, value was ><
Blank key found 2, value was ><
Blank key found 4, value was ><

array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Text' (length=4)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string 'Text' (length=4)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string 'Text' (length=4)
```

**Unset not working**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values_arr); $i++) {
    if ( empty($values_arr[$i]) ) {
        echo "<br> Blank key found " . $i . ", value was >" . $values_arr[$i] . "<";
        unset($values_arr[$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($values_arr);
```

**Output**

```
Blank key found 1, value was ><
Blank key found 2, value was ><

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Text' (length=4)
  3 => string 'Text' (length=4)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string 'Text' (length=4)
```

Why key 4 is not unset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $values_arr = array(
                   0 => "Text",
                   1 => "",
                   2 => "",
                   3 => "Text",
                   4 => "",
                   5 => "Text"
                );

    foreach($values_arr as $k => $v) {

        if(empty($v) || $v == "")
            unset($values_arr[$k]);

    }

    print_r($values_arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Text [3] => Text [5] => Text )
```

Why is your version not working?

Because in your for loop you have the condition: `$i < count($values_arr)`

So every iteration of the for loop it's going to check the condition! So if you unset a value in the array the count get's smaller! And after 2 unset's the for loop doesn't reach index 4 anymore!

Comment: Any idea why other one does not work i need to understand that more than find a working code.

Comment: @RomanToasov Your version isn't working because in your for loop you use count in the condition! So if you unset 2 index's it's not reaching  index 4 and doesn't get unset! So you would have to assign the count value before you go into the for loop!

Comment: Brilliant! I forgot that middle expression is for() evaluates every loop not just once. "In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated." http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that by the time you hit index `4` it will be equal to the size of your array and the loop stops.

There's a one-liner solution to this:

```
$values_arr = array_filter($values_arr, 'strlen');
```

It performs `strlen()` on each array element and returns a new array with elements that are not empty strings.

Another way is to find the keys corresponding to empty string values and then `unset()` those keys one by one in the main array:

```
foreach (array_keys($values_arr, '', true) as $key) {
    unset($values_arr[$key]);
}
```